# Why did this question get downvoted?

Tags: support, down-votes

I do try to follow the rules here, which I thought I understood, so could someone explain why this question was downvoted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608090/style-iframe-using-its-context-in-parent-page

Comment: Note that the down-votes were before the edit.  (At least one of them was, based on the comment you posted.)  Questions which basically say "here's a link to what I want to do, tell me how to do it" are often frowned upon.  I see the point of the question and wouldn't down-vote it myself, but others certainly might.

Comment: I see. I don't see how downvoting this meta question is constructive, I'm trying to learn. Seems some people around here are a bit trigger happy...

Comment: Note that down-votes mean something different on Meta than they do on the main site.  Here they often just mean that someone disagrees with what you're saying.  For a question like this, it may mean they disagree with your questioning of the votes, silently indicating that they think the votes were justified.  You shouldn't take down-votes personally there, and you _definitely_ shouldn't take them personally here.

Comment: ok, thanks for clearing it up, I'll probably just delete the orginial question and slave on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You demonstrate no effort.  In the eyes on the voters, you're just coming here and saying "Please write my code for me; I want it to do *X*".

People don't like that.

Comment: Got it. I have actually been looking into the issue for a day, only I can't figure out how to do it. Maybe I should have written that in the question.

Comment: @Chimoo The best thing to include in a question is *your code*.  Especially if it comes close.  That way, people are much more inclined to help you fix a little bug (and maybe upvote you for getting that far on your own) than they would be to do it all for you.

Comment: will do in future, I don't have any code on this as yet because I was more thinking conceptually and couldn't get my head around how to do it - writing code would have been pointless. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 4):

Also, any question that requires a user to visit another site are most often going to be downvoted and closed as not a real question.

Better to describe what you're looking for, possibly with images.